# unwanted spaces when animating after changing css

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im getting spaces between my div.container elements as soon as I changed the parent div to position relative and it needs to be relative is there a way to fix this. here is my jsFiddle example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wpfE/3/)

Comment: What browser are you running on? This is just a mess of boxes that move around randomly when I mouseover them in Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name change, eh?

```
next.animate({
   'left': next.offset().left + next.width()
});
```

The offset is giving you an offset from the edge of the screen and not your container.  That's why the gap is the same size as space between the left edge of the window and the box.

Comment: what do you mean name change what do i need to change

Comment: I meant you changed your name, you were Littleman or something the other day.  You can just subtract the parent element's offset left.